# How to send notifications from actions on google on a particular date and time

Tags: javascript, actions-on-google

I am making an action on google where I need to send a notification to the user on a particular date.I have searched the web but I couldn't find the solution.Can someone please tell me how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a chron node.js package? I.e., https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron or https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron

Comment: Thanks for reply,I will try it out and let you know.

Comment: Sorry for the delay,cron didn't work for me,I was losing reference to the cron job manager everytime.It was not getting stored

Answer (score 0):

Second the suggestion of a cron package however be mindful if you're running your backend on an event-driven stateless function (like [Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#do_not_start_background_activities) or AWS Lambda) that you may want to set up a separate service with an alternative architecture to handle notifications.